# Unknown provider in test with yeoman+angularjs+karma

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I'm new to angular testing and I'm already facing a problem.

I created a service through

```
yo angular:factory Flash
```

and once filled in it looks like

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ociWebPosApp')
  .factory('Flash', [
    '$rootScope',
    '$timeout',
    function($rootScope, $timeout) {
      var secs = 3,
        lastFlash,

        clear = function() {
          $timeout.cancel(lastFlash);
          $rootScope.flash = {};
        },

        show = function(message) {
          $timeout.cancel(lastFlash);
          $rootScope.flash = message;
          lastFlash = $timeout(clear, secs * 1000);
        };

      return {
        show: function(message) {
          show(message);
        },
        clear: function() {
          clear();
        },
        setLoading: function() {
          $rootScope.flash = {
            message: 'LOADING',
            type: 'loading'
          };
        },
        setApiError: function() {
          show({
            message: 'API_ERROR',
            type: 'warning'
          });
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

the testing file looks like

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: Flash', function() {

  // load the service's module
  beforeEach(function(){
    angular.module('ociWebPosApp',['ui.router']);
  });

  // instantiate service
  var Flash;
  beforeEach(inject(function(_Flash_) {
    Flash = _Flash_;
  }));

  it('should do something', function() {
    expect( !! Flash).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

The problem I'm having with testing is:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7) Service: Flash should do something FAILED
        Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: FlashProvider <- Flash
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=FlashProvider%20%3C
-%20Flash
```

I have already seen solutions in stackoverflow that take cases into account but I don't think that's the problem here as it's very simple 'Flash'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

I had 2 mixed problems. Not injecting dependencies in the first place and doing it wrong when calling for them.

As yeoman seems to add everything automagically I thought dependencies where added here too. I was wrong.

```
describe('Service: Flash', function() {

  // load the service's module
  beforeEach(module('ociWebPosApp');
  });
...
```

and then in `karma.conf.js` add the dependencies

```
...
files: [
      'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',


      'app/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',


      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'test/mock/**/*.js',
      'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Flash is undefined because it's defined in other function scope

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: Flash', function() {
    var Flash = null

  // load the service's module
  beforeEach(function(){
    angular.module('ociWebPosApp',['ui.router']);
  });

  // instantiate service
  beforeEach(inject(function(_Flash_) {
    Flash = _Flash_;
  }));

  it('should do something', function() {
    expect( !! Flash).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

Comment: I don't see any significant change. I only notices the `var Flash = null` going up but the rest remains the same, isn't it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: yes, I tried it but unfortunately it keeps giving an error :(